# Prove: Given that $R,S$ are equivalence relations then if $R \circ S$ is transitive then $R \circ S \subseteq S \circ R$.

Tags: relations

In another post entitled:  "Proof that composition of equivalence relations $R$ and $S$ is transitive if and only if $R \circ S = S \circ R$" the following proof is given for the forward direction.

Assume $R\circ S$ is transitive.  Let $(a,c) \in R \circ S$.  Then, for some b
, we have (a,b)∈R
and (b,c)∈S
.
Since the relations are symmetric, (c,b)∈S
and (b,a)∈R
, from which it follows by an earlier remark that (c,b)∈R∘S
and (b,a)∈R∘S
.
Now, by hypothesis, it follows that (c,a)∈R∘S
, whence (a,c)∈S∘R  ...
.

I understand why $(c,a) \in R \circ S$.  but why does this imply that $(a,c) \in S \circ R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd actually do it this way: we easily have

$$SR \subseteq RSRS \subseteq RS$$
where the first inclusion follows from reflexivity of $R$ and $S$, and the second from transitivity that is assumed of $RS$. So $SR \subseteq RS$. Using symmetry of $R$ and $S$, rewrite this as $S^{op} R^{op} \subseteq R^{op}S^{op}$.

The main thing to check now is $S^{op} R^{op} = (RS)^{op}$ for any relations $R$, $S$ whatsoever. It then follows from the previous paragraph that $(RS)^{op} \subseteq (SR)^{op}$. From this, $RS \subseteq SR$ follows easily.